# Assign 2 Numbers to each player from seperate array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 PHP Arrays, one is filled with players names

```
$players = array("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
                 "Player 4", "Player 5");
```

Another array is filled with numbers

```
$numbers= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
                "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
```

I'm trying to figure out how i can assign 2 random numbers to each player

This is where i'm at so far but it's not doing what i want it to.

```
foreach($players as $player) {
    shuffle($keys);
    echo $player." 2 Selections:<br />";
    echo $numbers[$keys[0]] . ',' . $numbers[$keys[1]];
    echo "<br /><br />";
    unset($numbers[$keys[0]]);
    unset($numbers[$keys[1]]);
    array_values($numbers);
}
```

Comment: What is `$keys`? `array_values($numbers);` has no effect, because you didn't use the returned value.

Comment: Why is shuffling once not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$players = array("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 5");

$numbers = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
// shuffle numbers just once
shuffle($numbers);

foreach($players as $player) {
    echo $player." 2 Selections:<br />";
    // `array_pop` takes the last element of array 
    // and reduces array at the same time
    echo array_pop($numbers) . ';' . array_pop($numbers);
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

See [the fiddle](https://3v4l.org/OnUv6).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say i only want each number to be selected once, Do i need to unset it once it's been assigned to a player?

Comment: No you don't need it. As `array_pop` __removes__ popped element from array.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by simply shuffling once and then not reusing the same Value like this

```
$players = array("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
                 "Player 4", "Player 5");

$numbers= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
                 "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
shuffle($numbers);
$nid = 0;

foreach($players as $player) {
    echo $player." 2 Selections:<br />";
    echo $numbers[$nid] . ',' . $numbers[$nid + 1];
    echo "<br /><br />";
    $nid += 2;
}
```

RESULTS

```
Player 1 2 Selections:<br />10,3<br /><br />
Player 2 2 Selections:<br />4,5<br /><br />
Player 3 2 Selections:<br />2,7<br /><br />
Player 4 2 Selections:<br />1,6<br /><br />
Player 5 2 Selections:<br />8,9<br /><br />
```

Also using this, the `$numbers` array is not actually destroyed and could be reused later if that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your aim, but your attempt is very close to working. The only problem is that you haven't actually defined `$keys` anywhere. If you define it at the beginning of the `foreach` loop based on the remaining items in `$numbers` (with `array_values`), it will work as desired:

```php
foreach($players as $player) {
    $keys = array_keys($numbers);
    shuffle($keys);
    echo $player." 2 Selections:<br />";
    echo $numbers[$keys[0]] . ',' . $numbers[$keys[1]];
    echo "<br /><br />";
    unset($numbers[$keys[0]]);
    unset($numbers[$keys[1]]);
}
```

Note that I've removed the last line `array_values($numbers);` because it doesn't do anything - `array_values` returns a new array, it doesn't modify it in place. You probably meant to write `$numbers = array_values($numbers);` but don't actually need to if you use `array_keys` as above.

Other approaches to the problem include:

- Shuffling the `$numbers` array directly, and using [`array_pop`](https://php.net/array_pop) or [`array_shift`](https://php.net/array_shift) to take elements from it.
- As above, but using a counter that you add 1 to each time rather than modifying the list, e.g. `$pick = $numbers[$i++];`
- Using [the `array_rand` function](https://www.php.net/array_rand) to pick the keys, and the same `unset` you have.

Comment: Oh yeah i missed that, Thank you it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any `$key` but I assume you already have it somewhere. *Please, next time show us the error message.* ;)

If you ask for **two random numbers**, use *rand()* to make your intent clear:

```
$players = array("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
                 "Player 4", "Player 5");
                
$dict = [];
foreach($players as $player)
{
    $numbers = [rand(1, 10), rand(1, 10)];
    $dict[$player] = $numbers;
}
```

But I think what you want is **two randomly selected numbers** so that no player share a number with another:

```
$players = array("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
                 "Player 4", "Player 5");
             
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
shuffle($numbers);

$dict = [];
foreach($players as $player)
{
   $two_numbers = [array_pop($numbers), array_pop($numbers)];
   $dict[$player] = $two_numbers;
}
```

Display Results:

```
foreach($players as $player)
{
    echo $player."\n";
    echo $dict[$player][0]."\n";
    echo($dict[$player][1]."\n");
}
```

EDIT: u_mulder was first when proposing "two randomly selected numbers". Just give it to him. FIFO!